# Select dropdown with ranges and search in database with between

Tags: php, mysql

I'm new in this field so please don't be harsh on me. It's looks simple yet I can't figured it out. So, I have dropdown select, like:

```
<select name="mode" id="mode">
    <option value="None">All</option>
    <option value="300-400">Inside</option>
    <option value="200-299">Outside</option>
</select>
```

Then I currently have this

```
$cMode=($mode == "None") ? '"%"' : $mode;

SELECT * FROM sections WHERE code LIKE '.$cMode.'
```

How can I change the query so if I select `Inside` to search between values 300 and 400?

Comment: is 300-400 stored as a string in your database or the values are stored as integers?

Comment: They are as integers. Each row in the table is single integer.. 300, 301,302.. etc

Comment: see the answer below, it will help

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `if-else` with `explode()` and `list()`

```
if($mode == "None"){
    $cMode = '"%"';
    SELECT * FROM sections WHERE code LIKE '.$cMode.'
}else{
    list($start,$eand) = explode('-',$mode);
    SELECT * FROM sections WHERE code BETWEEN $start AND $end
}
```

As you asked in the comment:-

```
  $cMode ='';
   if($mode == "None"){
     $cMode = 'LIKE "%"';
   }else{
     list($start,$eand) = explode('-',$mode);
     $cMode ="BETWEEN $start AND $end";
   }

$query = "SELECT * FROM sections WHERE code $cMode";
```

Comment: Thanks a lot. Both examples are working great but I like more the second one where is with one query.

Comment: @Ivanov  glad to help you :):)

Answer (score 1):

You can make `$cMode` dynamically by using `if and else` condition as:

```
   $cMode='';
   if($mode == "None"){
     $cMode = 'LIKE "%"';
   }else{
     $arr = explode('-',$mode);
     $cMode ="BETWEEN $arr[0] AND $arr[1]";
   }

$query = "SELECT * FROM sections WHERE code $cMode";
```

For more details [SQL BETWEEN Operator](https://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_between.asp)

Comment: Thanks but something isn't right because it doesn't return anything.

Comment: echo $query; and try to run in the database directly

Comment: Thanks for the help. I will use above answer.

Comment: Yes, that will do same

Answer (score 0):

I haven't quite understood what you were asking for, this is an example of how I print out data from rows with filters

```
<form action="PAGE.php" method="POST" id="users_selection">
    <select name="mode" id="mode">
        <option value="None">All</option>
        <option value="300-400">Inside</option>
        <option value="200-299">Outside</option>
    </select>
    <input type="submit" value="choose" name="choosing_user">
</form>
<?php
    $servername = "";
    $susername = "";
    $spassword = "";
    $dbname = "";
    $conn = mysqli_connect($servername, $susername, $spassword, $dbname);
    $mode = $_POST['mode'];
    $sql = "SELECT * FROM sections";
    $result = $conn->query($sql);
    if ($result->num_rows > 0) {
        while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
            $MYSQL_data = $row['data'];
            if($mode=="None"){
                echo '<p>'.$MYSQL_data.'</p>';
            }else if($mode=="300-400"){
                if($MYSQL_data>299 && $MYSQL_data <401){
                    echo '<p>'.$MYSQL_data.'</p>';
                }
            }else if($mode=="200-299"){
                if($MYSQL_data>199 && $MYSQL_data <300){
                    echo '<p>'.$MYSQL_data.'</p>';
                }
            }
        }
    }
?>
```

Comment: what happen if `options` got increased inside `select-box` . Your code is inefficient for handling any number of options. It's restricted to 3 options only.Try to learn how to solve the problem in generic not specific. Thanks

Comment: Hi @AlivetoDie , I've made this code within 5 minutes from an old code that I had because I didn't have much time left before leaving. I prefered to give an efficient answer for his question instead of modifying more things and be late, but I will be happy to make it better later on